# How can I push my submodules from github desktop?

Tags: github, heroku, git-submodules

Everytime when I try to push the files on myflix, the submodules myflixdb01 cant be pushed and when I try to push it from github desktop,I get an error"commit failed-exit code 1 received.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRqkH.png)

Comment: Check this out, it should help https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255#pushing-updates-in-the-submodule, normally the submodule lies in its own repo.

Answer (score 10):

I've just figured it out and it's easier than you might think.

Simply proceed to "Add existing repository" and then select your submodule from your local project directory, you should see a directory named `Submodules`.

[image]

After that, you can work with your submodule just the same as any other repository.

Comment: Easy maybe but not good user interface.. I just don't see what is submodule of what in browser need to look at path or rename it, but I solved it somewhat with aliases

Comment: Just wanted to add that I also had to change the branch from 'detached head' to 'main'